# Running Jenkins and Spring-boot on single EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2

I have a spring-boot application running on EC2 instance and it's publicly accessible from an elastic IP say `123.456.78.90` with the help of apache httpd server. I have given the following virtual  host entry in httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ProxyPreserveHost On
     ProxyRequests Off
     ServerName 123.456.78.90
     ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
     ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

Now, I have installed Jenkins on the same EC2 instance and want it to be accessible from my elastic IP `123.456.78.90` but maybe by specifying a different port like `9090` so when I give `123.456.78.90:9090` it takes me to Jenkins but when I give `123.456.78.90` it takes me to my spring-boot application. I am not sure what is the best way to configure it. For setting up Jenkins I tried the following virtual host entry in my httpd.conf file but its not working.

```
<VirtualHost *:9090>
     ProxyPreserveHost On
     ProxyRequests Off
     ServerName 123.456.78.90:9090
     ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
     ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

I would appreciate if I am pointed in the right direction.

UPDATE: I have the simple rule for directing the inbound traffic over http
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the port directly in jenkins, i.e. 8080 instead of routing it through apache?

Anyways I think the problem is due to the lack of a listening directive in apache for port 9090

See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/bind.html

Comment: I tried going to the ec2 instance directly over http://ec2-12-24.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080  but it's not responding. So, I installed apache and added the virtual host.

Comment: You need to open up the firewall in aws.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to follow the manual on https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+on+Ubuntu, the `Setting up an Apache Proxy for port 80 -> 8080` section. I think just change the 80 from 9090 and then the manual might work for you.

Also if you are using EC2, you may have to do some security configuration about the port that can be accessed from outside network in you AWS console